# TypeScript: How can I make an existing namespace global?

Tags: typescript, momentjs, typescript-typings, definitelytyped, tsd

I'm trying to stop using TSD for obtaining type definitions in a project that uses many libaries via global variables (the `outFile` option is used in `tsconfig.json` if this matters). In particular, it uses the Moment library in this way. Moment provides [its own type definitions](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.17.1/moment.d.ts) as part of the NPM package. However, these definitions don't declare anything in the global scope. Note that `moment` is both a global variable of type `moment.MomentStatic` and a type namespace at that. Using the NPM package, how can I augment the global scope in such a way that everything starts working as it works now with the old type definitions got from TSD? Namely, `moment` should be available globally, in any file, as both a variable and as a type namespace. Basically, what I want is something along these lines:

```
import * as _moment from 'moment';
declare global {
    const moment: _moment.MomentStatic;
    import moment = _moment;
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
[ts] Imports are not permitted in module augmentations. Consider moving them to the enclosing external module.
[ts] Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'moment'
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think that might be a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13175

Comment: Even if this gets fixed, how will I be able to declare a variable of the same name as the import alias? TS currently doesn't allow doing so.

Comment: Should `const moment: _moment.Moment` even be declared? I get `undefined` in my console if I try to access `moment.format` and the like.

Comment: In what console? Node.js? It assigns the global only in non-AMD and non-CommonJS environments. See https://unpkg.com/moment@2.17.1

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The type of the `moment` variable should be `moment.MomentStatic`, not `moment.Moment`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question. Finally I found a way to augment library typings in an old-school project that uses globals and `outFile`. We need a separate `.d.ts` for each library. Examples:

1. Adding compatibility with globals/UMD to Moment.js. To stay compatible with TypeScript 1.x, Moment's type definitions don't include the `export as namespace` line. A `.d.ts` file (named, say, `augment.moment.d.ts`) that fixes this:

   ```
   import * as moment from 'moment';
   export as namespace moment;
   export = moment;
   ```
2. Augmenting the type definitions for AngularJS. `augment.angular.d.ts`:

   ```
   import * as angular from 'angular';

   declare module 'angular' {
     interface IRootScopeService {
       $$destroyed: boolean;
     }
   }

   export as namespace angular;
   export as namespace ng;
   export = angular;
   ```

Comment: FYI, this is gonna be merged as a feature without your workaround: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57704.