# How do you add a typescript namespace from a node module to the global namespace?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, momentjs

I know that this is not best practice but I dont have a choice. The project I am working on has had its own moment typings file for a long time and it is now causing issues. Moment now provides its own typing file which I want to use, but I need to keep it global. How do I do this please?

I have tried just editing our moment.d.ts file inline with suggestions here
[[TypeScript: How can I make an existing namespace global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336330/typescript-how-can-i-make-an-existing-namespace-global][1]) which didnt work with an error of 'moment refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module'.

I have also tried editing the typescript config file to simply 'include' the the node module d.ts file but this gave me a no inputs were found in config file error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by creating a new global custom typing and a global value cosponsoring which is a separate moment instance. Super hacky and very temporary but works for now...

Comment: I've run into the same issue as you described in your original question that you solved. Would you mind posting a sort snippet of code that you used to create a new global typing and global value in a separate moment instance?

Comment: sorry but I dont remember and dont have access to the code now - i should have posted the snippets.

still i hope this helps you in the right direction

Comment: I think most likely i created the global custom typing - which you can find docs on - and then created a new singleton instance inferred as that type.