# VScode javascript Intelisense for typescript libraries without using import

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am developing a **web based** javascript app that uses a relatively big library (specifically pixi.js). That means InteliSense would be really usefull for both inline documentation and syntax hinting.

So far I have managed to activate InteliSense by downloading the npm package of this library and importing its original typescript files as if I was working on a node.js project: `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'`

The problem is, this will crash the script when trying to run it in a web. That means I have to choose between running the script and having InteliSense which is not optimal.

**Is there a way to achieve the same result without using the import keyword? (and therefore not crashing the script)**

I have also tried the triple slash reference which does nothing for me
`///<reference path="node_modules/pixi.js/lib/index.d.ts" />`

EDIT:
This is my package.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "pixi.js": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/pixi.js": "^5.0.0",
    "pixi.js": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you including the library in your app when you publish it on the web? and are you using any bundler (Vite, Webpack, Rollup, Parcel, etc.)?

Comment: How about installing just `types` as dev dependency? See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pixi.js

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I am including its minified version by <script> tag

Comment: And the bundler question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you're using the library by including a `script` tag for the minified, release version directly. That suggests to me you aren't using a bundler like Vite, Webpack, Rollup, Parcel, etc (which is fine). You *could* solve this by using a bundler; but you shouldn't *have* to.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792209/157247) I've figured out how to get the PIXI namespace types exposed as PIXI (to match the global the lib creates) globally for the project:

Create a `.d.ts` file to augment Pixi.js's type definitions, for instance `augment.pixi.d.ts`, with these contents:

```typescript
// Import the PIXI definitions
import type * as PIXI from "pixi.js";
// Export it as a namespace
export as namespace PIXI;
// Expose that namespace globally, to match the global
// variable pixi.js creates
export = PIXI;
```

Now, anywhere in your TypeScript code, TypeScript knows about the `PIXI` global the library defines and has the correct type for it. So for instance, if you type:

```
console.log(PIXI.
//              ^−−−− cursor here
```

...TypeScript knows what to auto-suggest for you (`ALPHA_MODES` and such):

[image: VS Code editor showing the user having typed PIXI. and the editor suggesting auto-completions like ALPHA_MODES and such from the Pixi.js library]

Here's the complete minimal project I created to make sure it worked:

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "pixitest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.json"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/pixi.js": "^5.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5"
    }
}
```

`augment.pixi.d.ts` as above.

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es2018",
        "outDir": "dist"
    }
}
```

`main.ts`:

```js
console.log(PIXI.ALPHA_MODES.PMA);
```

When I do `npm run build`, `dist` contains only `main.js`, which is (in this case) just the code from `main.ts` (since `main.ts` didn't have any type annotations in it):

```js
console.log(PIXI.ALPHA_MODES.PMA);
```